# Importing .dpr project with C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

I am a beginner in Delphi.
I want to know if I can import a (dpr) file extension in c++ builder 6?
What all changes I need to do for that?
I tried to do that and got the error

```
there was a problem sending the command to the program
```

If i want to run my application to all version of windows how can i do that(windows XP,Windows 7 and Windows 10).
Thanks

Comment: I don't see why C++-Builder would understand Delphi projects. If you have a Delphi project, build it with Delphi. And as for running on different versions of Windows, there's nothing stopping you doing that. Any details will depend on your program. You cannot expect us to list every single pitfall. Please refine your question to be more specific and narrow.

Comment: Thanks for the input, actually I tried googling it and found that there is a way of doing that by installing delphi personality. Is it correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. The error message you report is typically seen when double clicking on a file. Is that what you did? Is that how C++-Builder imports .dpr files?

Answer (score 1):

According to Remy's answer [here](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.cppbuilder.nontech/can-we-open-a-delphi-project-i/1082064) what you are trying to do is simply not possible.

> > When I try to open a Delphi Project with the file extension *.dproj or 
> >     *.dpr I get the message, " The Project can not be loaded because the 
> >     required personality Delphi.Personality is not available ".
>
> The C++Builder personality cannot load Delphi *projects*. You can,
>   however, add Delphi *source files* to a C++ project.
>
> > Is there a way to open and look at a Delphi project in C++Builder without 
> >     installing the full Delphi IDE?
>
> Not an entire project, no.